# Eureka client fail to fetch registry from (clustered) peer aware eureka servers

Tags: java, jersey, gzip, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

I have setup 2 eureka servers which successfully replicates registrations. Unfortunately when client app fetch registry through DiscoveryClient, response cause "java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format".

With single eureka server everything works fine, responses are not compressed so there is no zip exception (using compression is forced by eureka in peer aware setup https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/blob/master/eureka-core/src/main/java/com/netflix/eureka/GzipEncodingEnforcingFilter.java)

Eureka servers runs on Tomcats with enabled compression by setting compression="force" in HTTP connector in server.xml.

Response seems to be valid. It returns right header "Content-Encoding: gzip" and body is compressed. I have tested it with curl ("curl  -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" http://tomx11-ap01t.testbbh.com:9081/service-discovery/" with and without "--compressed" flag) and java client (I used HttpClient. I was able to decompress with GZIPInputStream).

Servers configurations:

```
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
         defaultZone: http://tomx11-ap01t.testbbh.com:9081/service-discovery/eureka
  server:
      enable-self-preservation: false
  instance:
    hostname: rdtasap33.testbbh.com


eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
         defaultZone: http://rdtasap33.testbbh.com:9081/service-discovery/eureka
  server:
      enable-self-preservation: false
  instance:
    hostname: tomx11-ap01t.testbbh.com
```

Client:

```
eureka:
    client:
      serviceUrl:
        defaultZone: http://rdtasap33.testbbh.com:9081/service-discovery/eureka,http://tomx11-ap01t.testbbh.com:9081/service-discovery/eureka
      register-with-eureka: true
      fetch-registry: true
    instance:
      instance-id: ${monitor.thisProcessorId}
```

Stack trace:

```
2018-01-16 13:02:04.967  INFO 6308 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
2018-01-16 13:02:06.907 ERROR 6308 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error

com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:140) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:509) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplicationsInternal(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:194) ~[eureka-client-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplications(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:165) ~[eureka-client-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) [eureka-client-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73) ~[eureka-client-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) [eureka-client-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) [eureka-client-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:118) ~[eureka-client-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:79) ~[eureka-client-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) [eureka-client-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) [eureka-client-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:119) [eureka-client-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) [eureka-client-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) [eureka-client-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) [eureka-client-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) [eureka-client-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1022) [eureka-client-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:936) [eureka-client-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:412) [eureka-client-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:267) [eureka-client-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.<init>(CloudEurekaClient.java:61) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.eurekaClient(EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.java:261) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$35174408.CGLIB$eurekaClient$0(<generated>) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$35174408$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$86e07ed2.invoke(<generated>) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [spring-core-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$35174408.eurekaClient(<generated>) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:345) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:379) [spring-cloud-context-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:181) [spring-cloud-context-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:340) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) [spring-aop-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getTargetObject(EurekaRegistration.java:166) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getEurekaClient(EurekaRegistration.java:155) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:56) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.register(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:37) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:80) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:175) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:50) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:348) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:151) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:114) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:880) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) [spring-context-4.3.12.RELEASE.jar:4.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134) [spring-boot-1.5.8.RELEASE.jar:1.5.8.RELEASE]
    at com.bbh.ilab.ants.dataprocessor.AntsDataProcessor.main(AntsDataProcessor.java:10) [main/:na]
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(GZIPInputStream.java:165) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:79) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(GZIPInputStream.java:91) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:133) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    ... 64 common frames omitted

2018-01-16 13:02:06.912  WARN 6308 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failed with message: java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format
```

What do you think guys?
My most latest guess is that something is wrong with http client (eureka use com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:1.19.1)

Answer (score -1):

This may be late in coming but did you notice that you are using register-with-eureka on the client and registerWithEureka on the servers?  Same for fetch-registry and fetchRegistry.  Try the camel case in all config files.  I ran into a similar issue.

Good Luck